# Cómo ocultar Google One Tap sign-in después de iniciar sesión

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-signin

He integrado Google One Tap sign-in y al momento de iniciar sesión o registrase genero una cookie

```
window.onload = function () {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: 'API KEY',
        callback: googleLoginEndPoint,
        skip_prompt_cookie:"FolioUsuarioSesionSite"
    });
    google.accounts.id.prompt();
}
```

Pero al volver de nuevo a la página donde inicié sesión, me vuelve aparecer el prompt de Goole, aún teniendo la sesión y de haber configurado

```
skip_prompt_cookie
```

Hay alguna forma de validar que cuando exista esa cookie o la sesión no lo vuelva a mostrar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que faltaba declarar al incializar el id de ese elemento, cómo se muestra en la documentación

Este es atributo que se tiene que declarar y lo del cookie

```
data-prompt_parent_id
```